# Eclipse gives this error: "Could not create the view: com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.LogCatView"

Tags: android, eclipse

I just installed Kepler, and when I try to run it under MacOSX, the logcat window contains nothing but this error message:

> Could not create the view: com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.LogCatView

In fact, there are several windows in the UI displaying similar error messages.

The key messages from the error log seem to be:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2013-09-07 10:14:16.836
!MESSAGE Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms/icons/logcat.png".
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms/icons/logcat.png".
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLHandler.openConnection(PlatformURLHandler.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.protocol.URLStreamHandlerProxy.openConnection(URLStreamHandlerProxy.java:112)
        at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:945)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLConverter.toFileURL(PlatformURLConverter.java:33)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImage(SWTPartRenderer.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.createTab(StackRenderer.java:680)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.processContents(LazyStackRenderer.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:649)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:676)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1042)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Is there something I need to do to install Kepler other than to unpack it somewhere and run ./eclipse/eclipse? That's always worked for me before. Should I do something special to uninstall the previous version of Eclipse?

Comment: It might be the case of eclipse android plugin might have not been installed properly..Please try reinstalling it..

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I foolishly thought that because the plugins were already installed, and the windows were showing up, that it should work. Reinstalling the Android tools fixed it. Make you're comment an answer, and I'll mark it "accepted".

Comment: glad that i could be of help to you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be the case of eclipse android plugin might have not been installed properly..Please try reinstalling it

Comment: I can't install android tools because they are already installed!  Now what?

Comment: +1. I'll be honest I didn't believe you, so I tried everything else. In the end, going to "Help->Install New Software" and re-installing android ADT plugin was the solution as the answer says.